# PHP time/date error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having some troubles with an event timetable. I'm trying to display all of the events for the said day, but it's only showing up with one. I'm using a little cms that somebody else coded. I'm just trying to fix the events page. Any help you could give would be much appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

        for( $i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++ ) {

            $query  = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM events WHERE day = '{$i}'" );
            $num    = $db->num( $query );

            $events = array();

            $day    = strtotime( "november {$i} 2010" );
            $day    = date( "l", $day );

            while( $array = $db->assoc( $query ) ) {

                $time = strtotime( "{$time} on november {$i} 2010" );

                $events[$time] = $array['id'];

            }


    ?>

    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="title">

            <?php

                echo $day;

            ?>

        </div>


        <?php

            if( $num != 0 ) {

        ?>

        <table width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">

                <tr style="background: #e9e9e9; font-weight: bold;">

                    <td width="40%">
                        Event Name
                    </td>

                    <td width="25%">
                        Host
                    </td>

                    <td width="20%">
                        Hotel
                    </td>

                    <td width="15%">
                        Time
                    </td>

                </tr>

                <?php

                    foreach( $events as $key => $value ) {

                        $query2 = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM events WHERE id = '{$value}'" );
                        $array2 = $db->assoc( $query2 );

                ?>

                <tr style="background: #f3f3f3;">

                    <td width="40%">
                        <?php
                            echo $array2['name'];
                        ?>
                    </td>

                    <td width="25%">
                        <?php
                            echo $array2['host'];
                        ?>
                    </td>

                    <td width="20%">
                        <?php
                            echo $array2['hotel'];
                        ?>
                    </td>

                    <td width="15%">
                        <?php
                            echo $array2['time'];
                        ?>
                    </td>

                </tr>

            <?php

                }

            ?>

            </table>

            <?php

                } else {

                    echo "<center>";
                    echo "There are no events for today!";
                    echo "</center>";

                }

            ?>

        </div>

    <?php
        }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding your `$day` variable in every loop and therefore only the last one will be shown. Same goes for the `$events` array

Comment: I tried removing the override of day and it just threw me an error. I'm not a PHP guru so it's harder for me to troublehsoot what the problem is, that's why I posted here.